# Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are regular, then so is the product space $X\times Y$.

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $X$ and $Y$ are regular, then so is the product space $X\times Y$.

How to show for general that if $X$ and $Y$ are regular, then so is the product space $X\times Y$? Is my answer below right?

Thank you.

EDIT - Definition: Let $X$ be a topological space. We say that $X$ is regular if (i) One-point sets are closed in $X$; (ii) For every $a \in X$ and every closed set $B$ in $X$ that does not contain $a$, there exist disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $a\in U$ and $B\subset V$.

Comment: Is my answer right? Thank you very much for your helps.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is to use the following definition of regularity:

> A space $X$ is regular if for every point $x \in X$ and open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, we can find an open set $A$ such that
>   $$
> x \in A \subset \overline A \subset U.
> $$

If you're not familiar with this definition, try to prove that it's equivalent to the definition you have. It should be a straightforward exercise.

Once you start with the definition above, there is only one way to proceed with the proof of the statement in your question. Let $W$ be an open neighborhood of $(x, y) \in X \times Y$. Then there are open subsets $U \subset X$ and $V \subset Y$ such that $(x, y) \in U \times V \subset W$. Use the definition above to find open subsets $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$ such that $A \times B$ is an open neighborhood of $(x, y)$ satisfying the desired property.

Comment: Sorry, I can't prove neither of conclusion from your definition to the book's definition or the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm basically just explaining section 31 of Munkres' topology. You should look at Munkres' topology if you haven't — it's a great book by a wonderful professor! We'll follow Ayman's advice to use this equivalent characterization of regular spaces.

---

**Lemma.** Suppose $ X $ a topological space where one-point sets in $ X $ are closed. The space $ X $ is regular if and only if given a point $ x \in X $ and a neighborhood $ U $ of $ x $, there is a neighborhood $ V $ of $ x $ such that $ \bar{V} \subset U $.

*Proof.* First suppose that $ X $ is regular and that $ x \in X $ and a neighborhood $ U $ of $ x $ are given. Let $ C = X - U $, so that $ C $ is a closed set. Since $ X $ is regular there are disjoint open sets $ V $ and $ W $ containing $ x $ and $ C $, respectively. Then $ \bar{V} $  is disjoint from $ C $ because if $ c \in C $ then $ W $ is a neighborhood of $ c $ disjoint from $ V $, so $ c \notin \bar{V} $. Thus $ \bar{V} \subset U $.

On the other hand, suppose $ X $ satisfies the "nonstandard definition of regularity". Suppose $ x $ a point of $ X $ and $ D $ a closed set not containing $ x $ are given. Let $ U = X-D $. Then by hypothesis there is a neighborhood $ V $ of $ x $ such that $ \bar{V} \subset U $. The disjoint open sets $ V $ and $ X - \bar{V} $ contain $ x $ and $ D $, respectively, proving that $ X $ is regular.                       $ \square $

---

Now we're ready to prove that the product of regular spaces is regular — we'll do this for arbitrary products, but if you want to just prove this for binary products the proof is obviously the same.

**Proposition.** The product of regular spaces is regular.

*Proof.* Suppose $ \{X_{\alpha}\} $ a family of regular spaces, and let $ X = \prod_{\alpha} X_{\alpha} $. Then since the product of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff (prove this!), one-point sets are closed in $ X $. Let $ x = (x_{\alpha}) $ be a point of $ X $ and let $ U $ be a neighborhood of $ x $ in $
X $. We use the lemma above to prove the regularity of $ X $.

First pick a basis element $ \prod_{\alpha} U_{\alpha} \subset U $. For each $ \alpha $ choose a neighborhood $ V_{\alpha} $ of $ x_{\alpha} $  in $ X_{\alpha} $ such that $ \bar{V}_{\alpha} \subset U_{\alpha} $. If $ U_{\alpha} = X_{\alpha} $, pick $ V_{\alpha} = X_{\alpha} $. Then by the definition of the product topology, $ V = \prod_{\alpha} V_{\alpha} $ is a neighborhood of $ x $ in (the product space) $ X $. Then since $ \bar{V} = \prod_{\alpha} \bar{V}_{\alpha} $, we see that $ \bar{V} \subset U $, so by the lemma $ X $ is regular. $ \square $

As a piece of advice, if you're not used to these kinds of arguments, draw pictures! You can almost always draw nice pictures in point set topology which really just tell you what the proof *has* to be.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. Let $P_X={\{\alpha}\}\in X$ be a closed one-point set in $X$ and $P_Y={\{\beta}\}\in Y$ a closed one-point set in $Y$. In addition, let $A={\{a_1, a_2, \dots}\}\subset X$ be a closed set in $X$ and $B={\{a_1, a_2, \dots}\}\subset Y$ be a closed set in $Y$. $A$ and/or $B$ can be countable or uncountable. Let $U_{1,2}$ and $V_{1,2}$ be open sets such that $P_X\in U_1$, $A\subset U_2$, $P_Y\in V_1$ and $B\subset V_2$.

Since the product of two closed sets are closed and the product of two open sets are open, therefore $P_{X\times Y}={\{(\alpha, \beta)}\}$ and also $A\times B$ are closed in $X\times Y$; and $O_1=U_1\times V_1$ and $O_2=U_2\times V_2)$ are open in $X\times Y$. Also, $P_{X\times Y}\subset {\{(\alpha, \beta), \dots}\}=O_1$ and $A\times B \subset O_2$.

Since $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$ and $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset$, so $O_1\cap O_2=\emptyset$. [=no common element in each 'component' so no common element in '$(x,y)$' type].

Comment: This answer assumes that all closed subsets of $X \times Y$ have the form $A \times B$. This isn't true in general.